# discord.py on_member_join not working @bot.event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Below is my code for a discord bot. I am trying to get it to change the server name to the amount of members in the server. I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111010/how-do-i-make-my-python-discord-bot-give-roles-on-join) but it did not work. Can anyone help? I do not receive any errors, and my output is also below. When I try and add the @bot.event for on_member_join, it does not seem to even get there.

### Output

```
Logged in as
Marwin
543266782601936898
------
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=543266782601936898&scope=bot
```

### Code

```
import discord
import json
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import aiohttp
from discord.utils import get
import json
from settings import bots
import pyjokes


TOKEN = open("token.txt").readlines()[0].strip()
prefix = "~"
bot = Bot(command_prefix=prefix, description="Ready to serve!")

# Runs when the bot is activated
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
    print(discord.utils.oauth_url(bot.user.id))

# @bot.event
# async def on_member_join(member):
#   print("asdsddad")
#   await member.send("Hello!")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    ''' @pong! '''
    await ctx.send('{0} Pong!'.format(ctx.author.mention))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def joke(ctx):
    ''' Tells a random programmer joke '''
    await ctx.send('{0} {1}'.format(ctx.author.mention, pyjokes.get_joke()))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def get_server_id(ctx):
    ''' Get's the server's ID! '''
    await ctx.send('{0}, {1}'.format(ctx.author.mention, ctx.message.guild.id))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("I made it to join!")
    await member.send('Welcome to the server!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def members(ctx):
    ''' Get members '''
    members = 0
    for m in ctx.guild.members:
        members = m.guild.member_count
    members -= bots[ctx.message.guild.id]
    await ctx.send('{0} There are '.format(ctx.author.mention)+str(members)+" members")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def change_name(ctx):
    ''' Change the server name! '''
    members = 0
    for m in ctx.guild.members:
        members = m.guild.member_count
    members -= bots[ctx.message.guild.id]
    await ctx.guild.edit(name = "The " + str(members) + " Dwarves")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you add any error codes, log files, or what effects the code achieves? More information will help people answer your question.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty I have done so

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [event decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=event#discord.Client.event):

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    ...
```

Comment: I have tried that in the past, but that did not work. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating both a `Client` and a `Bot`, you should only use one or the other.

Either change all of your `@client` decorators to `@bot` decorators or change your client line to `client = Bot(...)` and get rid of `client = discord.Client()`

Comment: I removed all of that, but that did not fix it :(

Comment: Your `on_member_join` is commented out, when I un-comment it your code works for me

Comment: Hey are you using discord.py 1.5? If so please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142666/4984749) on gateway intents

Comment: It looks like I am using version 1.1

Comment: v1.1 was released over 2 years ago, please update to at least v1.4.2

Comment: Thanks for having the idea to look at the version, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I updated to v 1.5 and it fixed it!